# Unable to use Appium inspector with WinAppDriver

Tags: appium, winappdriver, appium-desktop

I have WinAppDriver dunning in Windows 10

[image]

I am simply trying to start Windows calculator using Appium inspector but I get an error and I don't understand what's wrong

[image]

Can anyone give me some clues please?

Answer (score 0):

Appium Inspector is exclusive to mobile devices, doesn't work in Windows with WinAppDriver.

Use "Accessibility Insights": https://accessibilityinsights.io/downloads/

Or "WinAppDriver UI Recorder" instead: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run appium and add two more desired capabilities:

```json
{
  "platformName": "windows",
  "appium:automationName": "windows",
  "appium:app": "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
}
```

[image]